# Jquery: How to clear an element before appending new content?

Tags: jquery-ui

This is my jquery code

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "PopUpProductDetails.aspx",
            cache: false
     }).done(function (html) {
     $("#dialog").append(html);
 });
```

The first time, it works just fine. It display the content of the **PopUpProductDetails.aspx** page. But, after that, If I click again, I get twice the same content, and so forth. I believe the problem is that I need to clear the **dialog** element first, before appending new content.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`.append()` appends html to the end of existing html string, use `.html()` to replace what's currently inside of `#dialog`.

Comment: Note: `append()` works with more than just strings containing HTML, whereas `.html()` only works with strings containing HTML.

Answer (score 32):

Inside the function clear the dialog first and then fill up with the content

```
$.ajax({
   url: "PopUpProductDetails.aspx",
            cache: false
     }).done(function (html) {
     $("#dialog").html("");
     $("#dialog").html(html);
 });
```

Comment: Happy that the answer helped you

Answer (score 15):

You can use `.empty()` first, then use `.append()` in one line :)

like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "PopUpProductDetails.aspx",
        cache: false
    }).done(function (html) {
    $("#dialog").empty().append(html);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

in case you need to clear the dialog first use **.empty()** which is faster than **.html("")**

see [Jquery Difference .html("") vs .empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543711/jquery-difference-html-vs-empty)