# Jquery Difference .html("") vs .empty()

Tags: jquery, performance

In Jquery what is the difference between

```
$('#divid').html("");
```

and

```
$('#divid').empty();
```

Are both doing the same operating **internally** inside jQuery.js?

and which one is better to use.

Comment: The duplicate marking should include a link to the extant question

Comment: ``.empty()`` is **much faster**: http://jsperf.com/jquery-empty-vs-html/17

Answer (score 37, accepted):

T think `.empty()` is faster. [This](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L340) is the jQuery source for `.empty()`

```
empty: function() {
    var elem,
        i = 0;

    for ( ; ( elem = this[ i ] ) != null; i++ ) {
        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {

            // Prevent memory leaks
            jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );

            // Remove any remaining nodes
            elem.textContent = "";
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

And [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L367) is the jQuery `.html("")` source :

```
html: function( value ) {
    return access( this, function( value ) {
        var elem = this[ 0 ] || {},
            i = 0,
            l = this.length;

        if ( value === undefined && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
            return elem.innerHTML;
        }

        // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
        if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value ) &&
            !wrapMap[ ( rtagName.exec( value ) || [ "", "" ] )[ 1 ].toLowerCase() ] ) {

            value = jQuery.htmlPrefilter( value );

            try {
                for ( ; i < l; i++ ) {
                    elem = this[ i ] || {};

                    // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
                    if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                        jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem, false ) );
                        elem.innerHTML = value;
                    }
                }

                elem = 0;

            // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
            } catch ( e ) {}
        }

        if ( elem ) {
            this.empty().append( value );
        }
    }, null, value, arguments.length );
}
```

It's clear, you can choose your best.

Comment: ``.empty()`` is the boss! **much faster**: http://jsperf.com/jquery-empty-vs-html/17

Comment: After 7+ of years of JS development I finally learn this #facepalm

Answer (score 13):

I tried the following in JSperf and found out using $('#divid').empty(); is better

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js) of the `html` function, among many other things :

```
        if ( elem ) {
            this.empty().append( value );
        }
```

So `html` calls `empty`. Thus it's (marginally) faster to simply call `empty`. And of course it's more readable.

Comment: There is a lot more to the implementation `html` than this, if I'm interpreting it correctly it's not even running this code when you call `html` with an empty string.