# KendoUI Window Flashes Old Content

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui

Using KendoUI to display a popup window, I've noticed that if I reuse an existing window by calling `refresh` it briefly displays the old content until the AJAX request completes.

My code:

```
function clickHandler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var dta=this.dataItem($(evt.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    convertWindow.refresh({ type: "GET", url: "CallMeConvert?AppointmentId="+dta.AppointmentId});
    convertWindow.center();
    convertWindow.open();
    }
```

Is there any way to prevent this happening, or must I destroy and recreate the window every time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was, in the end, quite simple. You just need to clear the HTML immediately before doing the reset, like so:

```
$("#convert-window").html("");
convertWindow.refresh({ type:"GET", url:url }).center().open();
```

Comment: Apparently empty is faster. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543711/jquery-difference-html-vs-empty

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the window not when you start the refresh but when it finishes. What you need to do is use the `refresh` event:

```
function clickHandler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var dta=this.dataItem($(evt.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    converWindow.bind("refresh", function() {
        convertWindow.center().open();
    });

    convertWindow.refresh({ type: "GET", url: "CallMeConvert?AppointmentId="+dta.AppointmentId});
}
```

**NOTE** You actually don't need to `bind` `refresh` event every time, you can define it during the Window initialization.

```
var convertWindow = $("#my_window").kendoWindow({
    ...
    refresh : function () {
        convertWindow.center().open();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd like to vote up this answer, but I have insufficient rep! How stupid is that?!

Comment: I could, but I found a much simpler way which avoids a problem with this solution, which is that it delays the visual response to the button click until after the AJAX request is complete. I've self-answered what I did, and will accept that tomorrow. But this is a useful answer which I'd like to upvote.