# Kendo window close didn't clear properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a link that open a popup using kendoWindow. Everytime I close the popup and re-open again (from another link), the value from the first one wont clear at all. 
FYI, this kendo popup window is re-usable.

For example:
I have 2 link. Link A and Link B.

This link will call an ActionResult from the controller with parameter.

Link A will produce text = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
while link B will produce text = 'BBBBBBBBBBB'

```
//In controller:
public ActionResult Caller(string param)
{
    ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(); //This is a class that store a string.
    if(param == "A")
    {
        viewModel.Result = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    }
    else
    {
        viewModel.Result = "BBBBBBBBBBB";
    }
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So the flow are:
1. click the Link A. It will open the popup with value = AAAAAAAAAAAAAA.
2. close the popup.
3. re-open the popup from Link B. For a while, it will stay AAAAAAAAAAAAAA and after that (maybe taking about 2 secs) it will change to BBBBBBBBBBB.

If when in the slow bad connection, it will take times from changing AAAAAAAAAAAAAA to BBBBBBBBBBB.

My question is: 
Why the popup wont start as blank pop up (it still save old value on the layout)?

Thanks in advance,
Vera

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said it yourself, "*this kendo popup window is re-usable.*" Closing the popup window does not remove it from the DOM. It is simply being hidden. So, when it is opened again, it's content hasn't changed from before. You have to clear it yourself. The reason it takes a while for the content to update is because you have to wait for the round trip request/response from your server.

Comment: yes, but it should not keep the old content, I reckon. Because this never happen before.

Comment: I found a same problem in here. :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171552/kendoui-window-flashes-old-content

Answer (score 10):

Brett's explanation is correct. There are scenarios in which you simply want to display the same content again, so keeping the content is the "convervative" behavior. If the Kendo Window simply removed all its content each time it closes, you'd have to repopulate the content each time you want to show it again. This is less efficient than making the user empty the content explicitly when he knows he doesn't need it anymore.

In your case, you can simply use the close event to empty the window ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/BF69c/)):

```
$("#myWindow").kendoWindow({
    width: "300px",
    close: function (e) {
        $(this.element).empty();
    }
});
```

The other alternative is to destroy the window and create a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also got the same one in here, post by other. :)
I found a same problem in here. :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171552/kendoui-window-flashes-old-content

and yes, so its close. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

btw...The KendoPopup window is re-usable shouldn't mean that it should keep the old contents.

That should mean he is using the same Window control i.e. he doesn't have 2 Window controls on his form or html.

For the solution, he should use either

1) the deactivate event like this

```
win_deactivate() 
{
    this.destroy();
}
```

so that the Window is deleted from the DOM every time the window is closed.

Or

2) Define 2 window controls and show/hide one of them.

Comment: agree with you. Its never happen before. But lately, it does.

Comment: btw, I found a same problem in here. :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171552/kendoui-window-flashes-old-content
Thanks for the response :)