# JavaScript : Delete dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to web development and struggling with deleting a  dynamically created table.

Below is the JavaScript function to create the table when user clicks a button.

```
function DrawTable(data){
                  var oTHead = myTable.createTHead();
                  var oTFoot = myTable.createTFoot();
                  var oCaption = myTable.createCaption();
                  var oRow, oCell;
                  var i, j;

                  var heading = new Array();

                  heading[0] = "AAA";
                  heading[1] = "BBB";
                  heading[2] = "CCC";
                  heading[3] = "DDD";
                  var tableData = data.split(':');

                  // Insert a row into the header.
                  oRow = oTHead.insertRow(-1);
                  oTHead.setAttribute("bgColor","lightskyblue");

                  // Insert cells into the header row.
                  for (i=0; i < heading.length; i++)
                  {
                    oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1);
                    oCell.align = "center";
                    oCell.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                    oCell.innerHTML = heading[i];
                  }

                   // Insert rows and cells into bodies.
                  for (i=0; i < tableData.length; i++)
                  {
                    var oBody = oTBody0;
                    oRow = oBody.insertRow(-1);
                    var splitData = tableData[i].split(',');
                    for (j=0; j < splitData.length; j++)
                    {
                      oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1);
                      oCell.innerHTML = splitData[j];
                    }
                  }
            }
```

The above code works perfectly and draws the table when user clicks on the button.

If user clicks on the button again it will draw the table again.

i.e., it will draw another header and all the rows all over again.

At this point I want to delete the existing header and rows and draw it all new.

I tried many things to delete the existing table, but nothing works.

Is there a way I can make sure that the table is not duplicated again?

**UPDATE**

The HTML part is:

```
<table id="myTable">
                <tbody ID="oTBody0"></tbody>
            </table>
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

I tried below and it worked.

```
oTHead.innerHTML = "";
oTBody0.innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: So, what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: You're not actually creating a table here - just filling in `myTable`, which was presumably created elsewhere. If `myTable` is *not* being created each time, and your problem is duplicate contents, start the function off with `myTable.innerHTML = "";`. Just a guess, since we can't see where `myTable` came from.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `jQuery` when you're not using it?

Comment: @Bergi When you tag a question [tag:jQuery], it means that the asker is requesting that you use jQuery

Comment: @ThePixelBug: Yes, and I question that the asker actually wants that. He seems to prefer plain DOM methods.

Comment: I tried this: oTHead.innerHTML = "";oTBody0.innerHTML = ""; and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery offers a `.empty()` function that you can use

```
$("#myTable").empty();
```

Or with javascript you can just set the innerHTML to empty

```
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";
```

Just execute this function before you start trying to add new content to the table.

```
//$("#myTable").empty();
document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = "";

// Insert a row into the header.
oRow = oTHead.insertRow(-1);
oTHead.setAttribute("bgColor","lightskyblue");

// Insert cells into the header row.
for (i=0; i < heading.length; i++) {
    oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1);
    oCell.align = "center";
    oCell.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    oCell.innerHTML = heading[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, just do this: `$('#containerIdThatYourTableSitsIn').html('');`

That will clear the html of whatever element your table sits in. Then just reload it.

### Edit

As the comments have mentioned, .empty() is another option.

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but you risk getting leaky if data, events, or other references are not also cleared along with the html. $('#containerIdThatYourTableSitsIn').empty() might be safer?

Comment: @Radio: No, jQuery's `.html` method cleans up data before overwriting the contents. But you're right, `.empty()` is the better choice here.

Comment: Yeah! it stores data as an element attribute? That would make sense. I was more worried about future click events applied to cells.

Comment: @Radio: No, I said nothing about attributes. I meant that it explicitly calls `jQuery.cleanData`, to remove stuff like event handlers and other stuff.

Comment: Ah, thank you for taking the time to explain! More curious on the details, I found this, which may interest others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543711/jquery-difference-html-vs-empty